# How to programmatically change focus from devtools to page upon keyboard command

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible? [Keyboard commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) are detected even when the focus is within devtools.

Is there a trick using the chrome extension API to then defocus devtools and focus the page?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try calling window.focus() and document.focus() and dispatching a MouseEvent. Switching/closing tabs will be a measure of last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The API to change focus to a different window is: [`windows.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update). Specifically, the [`focused`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-updateInfo-focused) property. It can definitely move the focus away from DevTools windows. You would do something like to bring "the next window in the z-order to the front":

```js
chrome.windows.update(devToolsWindowId,{focused:false});
```

Alternately, you could instead focus a different specific window:

```js
chrome.windows.update(someOtherWindowId,{focused:true});
```